# Do callbacks in AbstractMongoEventListener are triggered when using Repositories?

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

Reading the documentation Spring Data Mongo, for the callbacks in AbstractMongoEventListener, they are called when some methods in MongoTemplate are used, i.e.

onBeforeConvert - called in MongoTemplate insert, insertList and save operations before the object is converted to a DBObject using a MongoConveter.

It's not clear if these also happen with CrudRepository custom methods such as findByName..
Do events also fire on usage of CrudRepository?